# How to Selectively load ArrayList content into a database

Tags: java

I currently have some code that loads some WAPT load testing data from a CSV file into an ArrayList.

```
 int count = 0;
 String file = "C:\\Temp\\loadtest.csv";
 List<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
 try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
       String line = "";
       while (((line = br.readLine()) != null) && (count <18)) {
            content.add(line.split(";"));
            count++;
       }
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      //Some error logging
 }
```

So now it gets complicated. The CSV file looks like this, the seperator is a ";".

In this case I want to ignore the first line, it's just minutes. I want the second row. I need to ignore "AddToCartDemo" and "Users". So the first 10 entries, in this case all ten 5's get loaded into the first ten columns of the database. Likewise the third row "Pages/sec" is ignored and the data after it is loaded into the next ten columns of the database, etc.

```
 ;;0:01:00;0:02:00;0:03:00;0:04:00;0:05:00;0:06:00;0:07:00;0:08:00;0:09:00;0:10:00;

 AddToCartDemo;Users;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;5;
 ;Pages/sec;0.25;0.1;0.22;0.65;0.03;0.4;0.43;0.17;0.22;0.4;
 ;Hits/sec;0.25;0.1;0.27;0.85;0.03;0.5;0.53;0.22;0.27;0.5;
 ;HTTP errors;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
 ;KB received;1015;4595;422;1600;2.46;4374;1527;1491;2551;2954;
 ;KB sent;12.9;3.66;13.8;39.9;5.22;21.7;23.8;13.2;12.2;23.1;
 ;Receiving kbps;135;613;56.3;213;0.33;583;204;199;340;394;
 ;Sending kbps;1.73;0.49;1.84;5.32;0.7;2.89;3.17;1.76;1.63;3.07;
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to caccomplish this? As usual a search brings up nothing even close to this. Thanks much in advance!

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: Do the decision making you explained just in between `line.split(";")` and `content.add(..)`. You can't avoid reading all content (and therefore putting it into memory), but you can discard as much as possible as early as possible.

Comment: What I forgot to mention: By discarding during reading you also avoid having everything in memory *at the same time*.

Comment: I've managed to trim the array list but I'm still unsure how to load the database so I have control over the contents of each array in the list.